# Trigger Camera on Google Glass

Tags: java, android, android-camera, google-glass, google-gdk

I want to have a way to trigger the camera on Google Glass right after I get in (e.g., "Ok Glass", "App", ) but I cannot find any similar examples online. 
Any idea how to trigger this?
Also, currently when I try to create a new Android project it will be the default Hello World, is there a template for Google Glass?

Answer (score 1):

On Ok glass you can write like -

```
    String fileUri ="file:///mnt/sdcard/Pictures/" ;

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // file:///mnt/sdcard/Pictures/MyCameraApp/IMG_20130812_105617.jpg

    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST);
```

Then you have to call -

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String picturePath = data.getStringExtra(
                CameraManager.EXTRA_PICTURE_FILE_PATH);
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

It will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch the built-in camera application immediately at the beginning of your application, you can call `startActivityForResult` with an intent whose action is `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` inside your initial activity's `onCreate` method. (But note the differences between Android and Glass with respect to how the captured photo is returned; see the [Glass `Camera` class Javadoc](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/media/Camera) for more details.)

Eclipse and Android Studio do not currently have any special support to generate Glass projects out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my sample Camera Snapshot on GitHub. It does exactly what you're asking.

Here it is:
https://github.com/dazza222/GlassCameraSnapshot